# Why can't I cancel an answer I started typing but changed my mind of which?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I started answering a question and after some typing I decided to not post it. I then got out of the page, but upon returning to the question to view later answers, I noticed that my typed text is again in the typing box, waiting for completion of the answer.

Deleting the contents of the box and getting out and in again, the text was there again!

Why can't I permanently cancel my intent to answer a question? Am I doomed to be permanently haunted by this ghost answer??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238). The good news is, that rogue draft will go way as soon as you write an answer to  different question. Something about the system only letting you have a single draft at a time, so a new draft (even to a different question) will overwrite the current one.